# How do I query queue ID in Apex?

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

### How do I query queue ID in Apex?

Known parameters:

1. Queue Name
2. Supported object

Miscellaneous information:
The reason I need queue ID in Apex because my *routing logic* assigns selected records to a queue on the click of a `commandButton`. Currently I have hard-coded the queue ID for testing.

```
record.OwnerId = '00GQ0000001nx6v';
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Queues are stored as a Group SObject, so

```
select Id from Group where Name = 'My Group' and Type = 'Queue'
```