# Need suggestion on Queue name check

Tags: trigger, class, validation-rule

I have one object where i am using one custom field (Queue_Name).
I am entering the queue Label in that text field.
I need to check wheather we are entering the correct queue Label present in Queues or else error needs to be appear.

Limitation-we cannot create a Queue as a lookup field.
Please suggest other option

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
select Id,Name from Group where Type = 'Queue'
```

Refer this

[How do I query queue ID in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10889/how-do-i-query-queue-id-in-apex)

Way 1 :
Create custom object 'Custom_Queue__c'  and populate name with the help of batch. Then look up this with your custom object. Which will help to prevent type the wrong name.

Way 2 : 
Put an validation in trigger and query and check the name entered in your custom object is valid.

Way 3:
Use both.

Comment: i just want to prevent users to enter incorrect QueueLabel which is not available in Queus.How to achieve this.Is this possible using validation/workflow?

Comment: workflow is not possible. Trigger validation is possible.

Comment: Why is way 2 not advisable vs changing data model. And should never do both. Way 1 should be custom setting and not custom object in most cases

Comment: Agree. Custom setting works instead of custom object.